# Quadratic behavior with std::regexp?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on a parser combinator library, and I've got a regexp combinator that checks if the stream matches a regexp at the current position.  This is what it looks like:

```
// execute parser
maybe<parse_match> operator()(parse_stream& stream) const {
    using std::regex;
    using std::cmatch;
    using std::regex_search;

    cmatch matches;
    if (regex_search(&stream, matches, regex_, regex_constants::match_continuous)) {
        return stream.match(matches.str(0).size());
    }
    return maybe_error("no match for '" + exp_ + "'");
}
```

Where it either matches and returns a struct containing pointers to the matching substring or returns an error.  &stream resolves to a const char* and I'm using a cmatch, so it shouldn't be building a string from the underlying char stream.

The problem, debugging some performance issues, is that this seems to be digesting the entire string each time.  If I parse a list of floating point numbers (eg: [3.14, 4.1348, 3.10134, ...] and print the time each regexp match takes, there's clearly a linear dependency on how much of the string I've parsed already, with the beginning showing exponential behavior!

[image: Regexp match time]

Is this expected behavior for regex_search?  Is there a way to retrieve just a single match from a larger string?  There doesn't seem to be looking at the docs...

Edit the first: I'm building the regexp with just the optimize flag:

```
regexp(string exp)
    : exp_(exp), regex_(exp, regex_constants::optimize) {}
```

Edit the second: PCRE2 does what I want with pcre2_match, so maybe they just got this part wrong...

Comment: To check only the current position you will probably need `std::regex_match` because `std::regex_search` matches any substring the whole text. So if it doesn't find it at the beginning it will trundle through the whole thing.

Comment: Also, for performance you probably can't get better than `PCRE`. Implementations of `std::regex` have yet to catch up on the performance side.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to avoid a dependency on PCRE, regexp shouldn't be _that_ big a part of the parsing problem.   regex_match won't work because it requires the entire string to match, and I obviously don't know how big the match will be before hand.

Comment: I would assume ending a `std::regex_match` with a `.*` (anything) should optimize very well.

Comment: Actually you could anchor your `std::regex_search` to the beginning using `^....` come to think about it.

Comment: That's what the continuous flag does, requires the match start at the beginning